# Get live data continuosly from API using Flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am in the process of building my first basic website using Flask in Python. I have successfully created a website where I retrieve values from an API (specifically, `ThingSpeak`), and I display them in a table. My current challenge is figuring out if it's possible to obtain live data from the API without having to rerun my code.

As it stands, each time I run the code, I fetch the values from the API. However, I am looking for a way to continuously receive updated values without the need to manually rerun the code. Is there a method or approach to achieve this real-time data update within my Flask application?

Comment: Is the data you want to show requested from an API which you built or do you request it from a third party service?

Comment: I request the data from a third party which is called Thingspeak

Comment: Unless they provide some "subscription" utility which would be a endpoint where you register and tell them to always send you new data your only option will be to rerun the code every x seconds to refetch the data

Comment: It depends what you mean by *"without re-running your code"*. You could put some Javascript in the HTML that calls `setInterval()` to get itself executed every 5 seconds or so. In that function, you could make an AJAX call to an endpoint in your `flask` script which connects to Thingspeak, gets some values and returns them to the Javascript, which could then add a row to your table... in my book, that wouldn't be re-running your `flask` app, but as I said, it depends what you mean.

Comment: What I am suggesting above also wouldn't cause your whole page to refresh either, just the bits that change, so it wouldn't even look like it was running afresh.

Comment: Hi Mark, I'm considering giving that method a try as I believe it could be implemented in my situation. Could you point me to additional resources or provide recommendations for further reading on this topic? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic idea is that you add a Javascript function (marked `1` in the code) into your HTML file that sets an interval timer (`2` in the code)  for, say, every 3 seconds. When that interval passes, a function (`3`) is called. In that function, you make an AJAX request (`4` in the code) to your flask (`5` in the code) app. Your flask app gathers the latest data and sends it back to the Javascript function (`6` in the code) which can then append a new line to the webpage with the latest data (`7` in the code).

I have put all the Javascript, HTML and Python in a single file and avoided all CSS, Jinja templating and error-handling so you can see how it actually works. You can add fancy styling yourself.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, url_for, redirect, session
app = Flask(__name__)

# This is the HTML, normally you would abstract it out into a template file and have Jinja render it
HTML = """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Continuous Update Demo</title>
 <!-- Pull in jQuery from Google-->
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
 <div>
   <h2>A continuously updated list:</h2>
   <ul id="culist">
   </ul>
 </div>

<script type="text/javascript">

function requestUpdate() {                         // 3

   console.log("DEBUG: requesting update");

   $.getJSON('/_refresh', function(result) {       // 4
      console.log("DEBUG: Received " + result.data);
      var HTML = "<li>" + result.data + "</li>";
      $("#culist").append(HTML);
   });

}

// This fires just once when the site initially loads
$(document).ready(function() {                      // 1
    console.log("DEBUG: document ready");
    // Get first element for list
    requestUpdate();
    // Ensure list is updated every 3s
    setInterval(requestUpdate, 3000);               // 2
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
"""

@app.route('/_refresh')                                # 5
def refresh():
    # print(request.args) to see what the Javascript sent to us
    print('DEBUG: Refresh requested');


    # Query your Thingspeak here and then pass the new data back to Javascript below


    # Build our response (a Python "dict") to send back to Javascript
    response =  { 
        'status' : 'Success', 
        'data': "A new line derived from Thingspeak",
    }
    print(f'DEBUG: Sending response {response}')
    return jsonify(response)                          # 6 - send the result to client


@app.route('/')
def main():
    print(f'DEBUG: Sending main page')
    return HTML

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Run this code with your web-browser's console turned on - it will be in your browser's *"Developer Tools"* or *"Debug Tools"* settings, then you will see all the messages.

---

You can obviously play around and tailor it to your own needs:

- change the update rate,
- CSS-style it better,
- add newest lines at top instead of bottom,
- cap the length of the displayed list and remove older elements as new ones arrive,
- handle the situation when there is no new data available from Thingspeak - maybe by changing the `status: "Success"` in the returned JSON object to `status: "Unchanged"`
- and so on...

---

Another, altogether different approach might be to open a web socket between **flask** and the Javascript. All the updates could then be initiated from the `flask` end whenever Thingspeak has an update, instead of the Javascript side checking every N seconds. That approach is described in [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77613721/2836621).

---

Here is a little video of it running. You can see the (very un-styled) webpage running at the top, the Javascript console below that and the output from `flask` below that in the black Terminal.

[image]

Comment: The solution provided was incredibly helpful. I successfully applied it to a standalone template, and it worked seamlessly. However, when attempting to implement it across my other templates using {% extends "base.html" %} as my base template, I encountered issues. Upon extensive testing, I discovered that the 'Pull in jQuery from Google' feature doesn't seem to be responsive. While I understand this goes beyond the scope of the initial question, do you have any insights into why this might be happening?

Comment: You could maybe try a different CDN - here are a few https://releases.jquery.com Just choose the one you want and there's a popup with the 2-3 lines you need to put in your `<head>` section instead of the Google one I was using.

Answer (score 1):

The third option and I would say probably best option is to use server-sent events. These function like a one-way websocket. It’s actually a streaming GET request. They are ideal for one-way realtime communication. They will be easier to set up and more reliable in the long run.

Check out this library - https://flask-sse.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html

(Advice based on a couple years working on a large-scale realtime chat application in production)

Comment: Cool - I was unaware of this technology.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is distinct from my other answer. In the other answer, the browser pings the server every few seconds for new data from Thingspeak - so it is effectively *"polling"*, which is fine for small projects and simple to implement and understand but not the most efficient in terms of bandwidth and server load. This answer uses web-sockets to connect the browser to `flask`. Then, whenever `flask` has new data available from Thingspeak, it can initiate the update of the screen by sending new data down the socket. So it is more a *"push"* type of application and no-one is doing anything unless there is new data:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# Pre-requisites
# pip install "Wekzeug>-2.0.0rc3"
# pip install flask-sock

# Run with flask development server:
# FLASK_APP=FlaskSock.py flask run

# Or run under gunicorn:
# pip install gunicorn
# gunicorn -b :5000 --workers 4 --threads 100 THISFILE:app

################################################################################
# HTML/Javascript part - just wanted to avoid a whole bunch of files/directories
################################################################################
HTML = """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <title>Websocket Demo</title>
  <!-- Pull in jQuery from Google-->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>WebSocket Demo</h2>

    <body>
       <div>
          <h2>Another continuously updated list:</h2>
       <ul id="culist">
       </ul>
    </div>

    <script type="text/JavaScript">
      // Create websocket
      var ws = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:{{port}}/ws');

      // Whenever new message received, update display
      ws.onmessage = function(event) {

        console.log('DEBUG: Received ' + event.data);

        var HTML = "<li>" + event.data + "</li>";
        $("#culist").append(HTML);
      }

      // Send first message to get server to start sending updates
      ws.send('GO!');

    </script>

  </body>
</html>
"""

################################################################################
# Python part
################################################################################
from flask import Flask, render_template_string
from flask_sock import Sock
from time import sleep

port = 5000
app = Flask(__name__)
sock = Sock(app)

@sock.route('/ws')
def anything(ws):
   print(f'DEBUG: websocket endpoint called')
   while True:
      for i in range(10):
         data = f'Line {i} from server'
         # Send the new data to the front-end via websocket
         ws.send(data)
         sleep(2)

@app.route('/')
def main():
    print(f'DEBUG: Sending main page')
    return render_template_string(HTML, port=port)
```

The output is pretty much the same as my other answer which has a little animation.